# How to delete S3 object using cronjob

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, cron

I have a python file in my EC2 which connects to S3 and deletes all versions of objects.

My **S3delete.py**

```
session = boto3.Session()
s3 = session.resource(service_name='s3')
bucket = s3.Bucket('mys3bucket-delete-me')
bucket.object_versions.delete()
```

In my **job.sh** I call this python file

```
#!/bin/bash
python s3delete.py
```

Make my file executable `chmod +x job.sh` and execute `./job.sh`

This works fine and deletes all objects of my s3 bucket.

Issue is when I call this `job.sh` within crontab `sudo crontab -e` every minutes but the file is not deleted.
`*/1 * * * * /home/ec2-user/job.sh`

Please guide me what's wrong?

*Update*

I checked the server `date` which showed `Sun Jun  6 04:48:36 UTC 2021` and edited the cron line to export the logs to a file.

`50 4 * * * /home/ec2-user/job.sh > /tmp/s3delete.log`

Checked the log file after 2-3 minutes and it is empty.

I also checked if the crontab is running `[ec2-user@server ~]$ ps aux | grep crond`

```
ec2-user  5295  0.0  0.0 112812   968 pts/0    S+   04:55   0:00 grep --color=auto crond
```

Comment: What does "doesn't execute" mean?  Do you get an error?  If so, what  is it, specifically?  Do yoyu have all your environment variables set up?  In a cronjob, many environment variables may not be set.....

Comment: Try saving a logfile as part of the cron job and then see what is contains, eg: `python s3delete.py >/tmp/s3delete.log`

Answer (score 0):

The first suspect is that the aws credentials is not accessible in the bash. So include the same as given below :

```
session = boto3.Session(
    aws_access_key_id=ACCESS_KEY,
    aws_secret_access_key=SECRET_KEY,
    aws_session_token=SESSION_TOKEN,
)
```

S3delete.py becomes :

```
session = boto3.Session(aws_access_key_id=ACCESS_KEY,
    aws_secret_access_key=SECRET_KEY,
    aws_session_token=SESSION_TOKEN,)
s3 = session.resource(service_name='s3')
bucket = s3.Bucket('mys3bucket-delete-me')
bucket.object_versions.delete()
```

Comment: Ali - I mentioned that my job.sh works fine which calls the s3delete.py, so my EC2 is using a role which has s3:* permissions.

Comment: Can you check if crond is running with ps aux | grep crond

Comment: [ec2-user@server ~]$ ps aux | grep crond

Comment: root      2774  0.3  0.0 126392  1684 ?        Ss   04:34   0:00 /usr/sbin/crond -n

Comment: ec2-user  2959  0.0  0.0 112812   968 pts/0    S+   04:36   0:00 grep --color=auto crond

Comment: Looks like the cron service running .Then it must be the env variable are not included  in the cron environment. Try changing the cron line  50 4 * * * $HOME/.profile; /home/ec2-user/job.sh > /tmp/s3delete.log